# JS: call element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not familiar with JS, so please help me here

I've used to call element like this before:

```
$(.ddlPage).change();
```

Now I would like to replace 'ddlPage' with a string variable.
How can I call it with variable?

```
$(.elemID).change(); (is obviously wrong)
```

Comment: it's not js, it's jQuery, which is js, but not vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, pass a string parameter to jQuery. In your case (if it is not a typo) you pass some variables in there, which works in some cases, but not in general.

Then just build the selector you need, so, e.g.:

```
var elemId = 'myId'; 
$( '#' + elemID ).change();
```

Or to search for a `class`:

```
var elemClass = 'myClass'; 
$( '.' + elemClass ).change();
```

etc. Just built up a string containing the selector you need and pass it on to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `id` selector

```
$("#ddlPage").change()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is a basic understanding of jQuery selectors.

Review the material here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: @Sirko I think for the bare-bones basics of jQuery selectors, W3CSchoole suffices. Good info though. :)